# Android SharedPreferences revert to previous versions after immediate reboot

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm working on Android 5.0 SDK with custom device and found this problem:

1. modify settings in UI, then the setting will be stored in the share preference. The time stamp of the share preference file is 2018-09-06 21:12.
2. Immediate unplug the power of the device, then plugin the power, then check the share preference.
   The time stamp of the share preference file is 2018-09-06 21:04.

This means that the share preference file was replaced by a previous version during reboot.

commit is used in shared preference, so the file is already written in disk in step 1.

Code:

void setPreferences(Context context, String key, Integer value) {

```
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putInt(key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Does anyone know what's the reason for this?

Comment: Can you share your code on how your shared preference is updated please?

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putInt(key, value);
        prefsEditor.commit();

Comment: Android is a Linux based system. Disk writes are often delayed. Check [What's the philosophy behind delaying writing data to disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224415/whats-the-philosophy-behind-delaying-writing-data-to-disk)

Comment: Share your shared preference code

Comment: And how do you get `appSharedPrefs`? Can you edit your question above to include all your code for the SharedPreferences please.